# Why Rogue One name (and not something more appropriate)

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

I watched Episode 3½ (Rogue One) and cannot understand why the name is Rogue One? It is the name of stolen ship but is this ship so important to name the film? Nothing more important than this... "The Death Star" (for example) would be more clear and understandable name.

Comment: @Gallifreian I found this question but it is different. It is posted before the movie was available and the name seems unknown (what means). My question is "why" this name, not "what means".

Comment: It'd be a good idea to outline how exactly your question is different from the linked one, in the question body and the title. That'll repel downvotes and close votes

Comment: It is also not episode VIII that will be the sequel to episode VII The Force Awakens. This is a prequel to episode IV A New Hope.

Comment: @Gallifreian The linked question is asked in April 2016 when the contents of the movie are unknown. The man wants to know the origin of the name and how it was chosen. My question is little different - I think the name is absolutely formal. Like somebody has no imagination and get the name of stolen ship. My question is "Why the name is not different - something more appropriate" and not "how they go to decision for exactly this name".

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn For that reason I have added (version 3.5) between 3 and 4.

Comment: @i486 maybe you should remove the episode VIII reference totally as it will get confusing when the actual episode VIII comes out

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn OK, agree. And this (the undefined number of this episode) is another similar question :)

Answer (score 3):

The name 'Rogue One' was made up on the spot when the team decided to go against orders and try to get the Death Star plans anyway.  When they tried to lift off, traffic control called demanding to know who they were and why they were leaving.  When asked their 'call sign', the pilot answered 'Rogue' because they were, in fact, about to 'go rogue', then when asked 'Rogue *what*?' (i.e 'what is the number of your call sign?'), gave the first number that came to mind: One (since they were the first to go rogue).